# How to make case-sensitive search for Sqlite database engine? Error near "COLLATE":

Tags: android, sqlite

1. I am using this query...

   > Cursor cursor = sqliteDb.query(DB_Table, null, "col like " + "\""
   >               + fetchingstring + "%" + "\"", null, null, null,
   >               "COLLATE BINARY");
2. And when I perform search for this, it gives me the error:

   > 01-19 11:13:29.134: E/AndroidRuntime(1707): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException:    near "COLLATE": syntax error: , while compiling: SELECT * FROM tablename ORDER BY COLLATE BINARY;
3. In my Sqlite database, I already did the column with COLLATE BINARY. So please help me where I am going wrong with this. Thanks V.K.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use glob instead of like to make search case sensitive..

```
 Cursor cursor = sqliteDb.query(MY_DB_Table_Name, null, "col glob"+ "*" + "\"" + fetchingstring + "*" + "\"", null, null, null, null);
```

Using same this query,we can make search case sensitive in sqlite.

Answer (score 1):

change

```
 COLLATE BINARY  to      COLLATE_BINARY
```

and

```
 "col like " + "\""+ fetchingstring + "%" + "\""  TO  "col like '"+ fetchingstring + "%'"
```

Comment: add this change , and run again,, if error comes , add error and your table structure, and the fetchstring value it will help to solve it

Comment: It is showing error this,plz check it.01-19 12:58:18.509: E/AndroidRuntime(6432): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: COLLATE_BINARY: , while compiling: SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE col like "sa%a%" ORDER BY COLLATE_BINARY

Comment: you need to replace your column name with new one, and dont forgot to uninstall your app from emulator/phone then reinstall it,, as database changes only occur if app installed freshly

Comment: Ankit i did as you told me but it not giving any change in my result.i changed my database data type to collate binary as well as other changes that needed.But nothing get.

Comment: Edit your question, add Create_table String in your question, and the query , will run it at my side..

Answer (score 0):

As per the doc of Sqlite, you should have created a db with collate word...

Pl. See the doc [here](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).

Comment: I already did it in my db.I read this doc and then changed in my db but it still giving error.

Comment: I presume we should only select the column which have collate, try replacing the * with the column name

Comment: In My database i changed according doc but its not working.No change in filteration of search.

Answer (score 0):

I think sqlite expect a column name between the ORDER BY and the COLLATE. Maybe you can try something like this:

```
Cursor cursor = sqliteDb.query(DB_Table, null, "col like " + "\"" + fetchingstring + "%" + "\"", null, null, null, "col COLLATE BINARY");
```

Assuming `col` is a valid column in your table.

Comment: Sorry,it didnt work for me.Using this,it gives same result as before.It work same as null work for this.

Comment: Does the result is not the one you expected, or does it throw an error?

Comment: Ok, in my own project, i had to had `COLLATE NOCASE` because i wanted to sort case-insensitively. If i did this, it should be because the default sort order is case sensitive, so maybe try to remove the `COLLATE` part, and just leave the column name in the order clause, e.g. `sqliteDb.query(DB_Table, null, "col like " + "\"" + fetchingstring + "%" + "\"", null, null, null, "col")`

Comment: it not thrown the error but i am not getting that result i expect.Simply i made my db coloum COLLATE BINARY then i make the query as u told.But it has not given any change in my result.Now i try it without COLLATE Binary simply with col.